# Eastin Knill Theorem and global phase

Tags: error-correction, mathematics

In quantum we don't care about global phases, but I want to ask a question about global phases anyway.

The original Eastin-Knill theorem paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.4262 says
$$
CP = \Pi_{i=1}^k e^{iDk} P ∝ P
$$
which is true. Below this equation it says "Since $ C $ is a unitary operator, the constant of proportionality must be one." This is obviously false since $ C $ could be a global phase. Is there a typo and "one" is supposed to be "norm 1"?

Furthermore, in the next column, it says
$$
GP = FCP = FP
$$
which is false and should really read something like
$$
GP = FCP = Fe^{i \theta_C} P
$$
where $ e^{i \theta_C} $ is some global phase dependent on $ C $ and not necessarily equal to $ 1 $.

Granted, this doesn't affect the actual point of the paper since $ \mathcal{F} $ is still finite. And global phase isn't really a logical operation since we usually thinking of logical operations as being projective unitaries. So it's still fair to say the set of logical transversal gates is finite. And certainly the logical transversal gates are still not universal.

It's a small detail but I just wanted to bring it up to see if I'm missing something or if it really is just an (unimportant) error in the paper.

Comment: I think you can get a stronger finiteness by assuming that either $C$ or its restriction to the code space is special unitary, but I don't see anything in the paper to suggest the constant of proportionality must actually be $1$